# What is the proper way to declare a global variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

So, I was wondering what the proper way to declare a global variable is in an iOS Project.
I don't want it set as a property, because the variable should not be accessible from outside the class.

I am going to provide a few ways I have seen, let me know which is the proper way, and if there is another way that is better.

This way I add the global variable inside curly braces after the `@interface` declaration in the implementation file `.m`. Then I can initialize the variable in the `viewDidLoad`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    int globalVariableTest;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController
```

Another way I add the global variable inside curly braces after the `@implementation` declaration in the implementation file `.m`. Again intializing in the `viewDidLoad`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController {
       int globalVariableTest;
}
```

Another way is adding the variable after the `@implementation` without the curly braces, also this allows me to set the intial value without the `viewDidLoad`

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

int globalVariableTest = 1;
```

Another way is to add the variable after the `@interface` inside the header file `.h`

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int globalVariableTest;
}
```

So if there is a better way please let me know, all help will be appreciated!

Comment: A truly global variable would be defined as `int globalVariableTest` in the .m file, and declared as `extern int globalVariableTest` in the .h file. Then, you import the h. file into every other .m file that wishes to access the variable. By the way, this is valid not only in Objective-C but C and C++ too.

Comment: Where at in the .m file? I see it done so many different ways, is there a difference?

Comment: Outside any `@interface`/`@end` or `@implementation`/`@end` block (in the so called "global scope"); for example, near the very top (right after the `#import`s).

Comment: By the way, what you were trying to use is an instance variable, and it only lasts for as long as the instance of your view controller exists. What I explained is a global variable, not attached to any transient object. It exists throughout the whole life of the application.

Comment: I only want it to exist while the view controller is active.

So I changed it to this:

`#imports ...  blah blah`
`int globalVariableTest = 1`

But when I incremement or change the variable in my code, and try to log it out later, its always 1

Comment: If it is an instance variable, you can only access it through the view controller instance. Use a `@property` instead.

Comment: "I add the global variable inside curly braces after the @interface declaration" - then that's most definitely **not a global variable.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring variables inside curly braces is actually declaring an *instance variable* or "ivar" for short. That is, a variable that's local to *instances* of your class.

This used to only be possible after `@interface` declarations, which is why you sometimes see it there. This changed around Xcode 4 so that you can now do it after `@implementation` also. As far as I'm aware, this is just stylistic preference. ivars are never accessible outside a class (in theory. Technically, everything is accessible to everything in C), so defining them in the .h won't make them public. It does expose an implementation detail, though, which is why most code I see now that uses them puts them in the `@implementation`.

But I don't see them much in code anymore. Because when you define a `@property` what is actually happening under the covers is an ivar, a getter method, and a setter method are all actually being synthesized for you. The getter and setter methods just get the value of the ivar and set the value of the ivar, respectively.

So if what you want is something that has the same scope as a property, but doesn't come with the `-myVar` and `-setMyVar:` methods, then this is the right way to go.

But you probably shouldn't want that. There are a whole bunch of reasons that it's nice to only access ivars through accessor methods. It lets you override functionality, translate values, and all the other sorts of fun things abstraction affords you.

If what you want is a `@property` that isn't accessible outside the class, just declare it in a class extension:

```
//In MyClass.m
@interface MyClass()
  @property NSNumber *myProperty;
@end

@implementation MyClass
  //All your implementation stuff here.
@end
```

Because it's not in the .h file, it won't be "visible" to other classes (In theory. See above about everything being visible in C).

If on the other hand, what you really truly want is something that is really truly global (hint: you shouldn't. Global variables are generally a smell of bad design), you need to define it at the top of your file outside any `@interface` or `@implementation` blocks.

Another related tidbit: To define a "global" variable with a scope limited to a given file, look into C's `static` keyword. It's interesting.

Comment: I misused the term Global in my question. My apologies. However I think you answered my question exactly. To clarify. In the `.h`, properties set there, can be seen from another class if imported. But if I only want a variable to be accessible from this one particular class, declare it inside the `@interface` within the `.m file`?

I've always wondered what the purpose of the `@interface` was within the `.m file`

Comment: Yes, exactly! If that's all you need to know stop reading, but if you want details: An `@interface` block followed by `()` instead of a superclass is actually defining a ObjC *category*. Normally you have to specify a name in the parens, and a separate `@implementation` that matches that name, but specifying nothing makes it an *anonymous category* also sometimes called a *class extension*. Pretty much the only use of this is to let you define interfaces for things outside of .h files so that they don't get exported to other classes.

Comment: I added the property in the .m: `@property (nonatomic) int currentTag;` I intialized the variable in the viewDidLoad: `_currentTag = 1;` and when I increment the variable throughout my code, it works, I output the result and it indeed is incrementing by 1. But when I try to log out the message in another function later, it just logs out 1? Any idea what may be going wrong?

Comment: When I try to log out the value of the variable, it is always the value which I set it to in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: If you don't do any setter- or getter-magic inside the properties and you need to improve performance, you should use the ivars directly wherever possible. My colleague is currently writing his master thesis about energy consumption and performance of mobile apps. For Obj-C he found lower energy consumption and higher performance when using ivars instead of properties. Since the invention of ARC there isn't even the memory management for objects on the pro-side anymore...

Comment: @StefanJager True. Direct ivar access is more performant (doesn't have the overhead of a call to `objc_sendMsg`), but that overhead is *very* small, even in tight loops… especially when the property is `nonatomic`. The increase in abstraction is worth the tiny performance penalty in 99.999% of use cases. Prematurely optimize at your peril.

Comment: @BobbyW No idea. Do you have a project you can share?

Comment: He tested some cases and if I'm not completely mistaken, there was a scrollview that was sloppy and stuttering while scrolling when using properties but soft and smooth when using ivars. I'll ask him to give me the numbers, so I can post them here. This doesn't mean to ban properties completely from all your projects. But why use them in cases where you don't need them?

Comment: @StefanJager Because there's never a case where "you don't need" abstraction, and *that's* what properties provide. There may rarely be cases where the tradeoff between abstraction and performance needs to shift towards the performance side. But to forgo properties in cases where you think you might not need them because you think that maybe you might need the performance is the very definition of premature optimization.

Comment: If the property simply returns or sets _foo and you're only using it inside the defining class (which is the case if you define it in a class extension), why not set or use it directly? Why call self.foo instead of _foo?

Comment: @StefanJager Simple answer? It's bad design. That values are stored in `_foo` is an implementation detail. Accessing `_foo` directly violates this abstraction. If the only reason you have for purposely committing bad design like this is performance optimizations that you're not sure you need, that's a bad tradeoff. Example? Six months down the road you decide you want to add cacheing around `foo`. If everything was calling getters and setters as they should have been, no problem. If some things were using `_foo` directly, now you've got a lot of searching and bug fixes ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton class to create/share (read / write) all variables across different classes (view controller).

.h

```
@interface SharedVariables : NSObject  {
    NSDictionary *dicti_StackSites;
    NSDictionary *dicti_UserMe;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *dicti_StackSites;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *dicti_UserMe;

+(id)sharedVariablesManager;

@end
```

SharedVariables.m

```
#import "SharedVariables.h"

@implementation SharedVariables
@synthesize dicti_StackSites;
@synthesize dicti_UserMe;

+(id)sharedVariablesManager {
    static SharedVariables *sharedVariablesClass = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedVariablesClass == nil) {
            sharedVariablesClass = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedVariablesClass;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        dicti_StackSites = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
        dicti_UserMe = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
}

@end
```

Usage from any other class

```
#import "SharedVariables.h"

SharedVariables *sharedManager = [SharedVariables sharedVariablesManager];

//to get sharedManager.dicti_StackSites
//to set sharedManager.dicti_StackSites = ...
```

Comment: He mentioned in the comments that he needs the variable only during the lifetime of his view controller, so I don't think he needs a singleton...

Comment: @NicolasMiari I did not read the comments. Either question or comments wrong then

Comment: Shouldn't dicti_StackSites be released explicitly ?